# How do I issue keyboard shortcuts like horizontal split in a nested Byobu session?

Tags: byobu

Ctrl+F2 and Shift+F2 create vertical and horizontal splits in Byobu. But when I ssh into another Byobu session, those key combinations affect the local Byobu only, not the remote one.

Same goes for the Shift+arrow keys to move around the splits.

How can I perform these actions on the remote session instead?

Answer (score 0):

XTerm (*xterm*) from the default Ubuntu repositories is a standard terminal emulator for the X window system. An xterm is able to capture and support far more key presses than a remote console. From [How to forward X over SSH from Ubuntu machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine/12772#12772):

> X11 forwarding needs to be enabled on both the client side and the server side.
>
> On the client side, the `-X` option to `ssh` enables X11 forwarding, and you can make this the default (for all connections or for a specific connection) with `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config`.
>
> On the server side, `X11Forwarding yes` must specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Note that the default is no forwarding and that the user cannot override this setting.
>
> The `xauth` program must be installed on the server side. If there are any X11 programs there, it's very likely that `xauth` will be there.
>
> To confirm that ssh is forwarding X11, check for a line containing `Requesting X11 forwarding` in the `ssh -v -X` output. Note that the server won't reply either way.